# Named export not recognized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import

I have a structure like this:

```
routes
  auth
    login
      index.js
      Login.jsx
    routes.js
```

in the `routes.js` file I have the following:

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Login } from './login';

export default (
  <div>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  </div>
)
```

in the `login/index.js` I have this:

```
import Login from './Login';

export const Login;
```

but for some reason I'm getting this error:

> Attempted import error: 'Login' is not exported from './login'.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: I'm getting an error for `export const Login;`: Parsing error: Identifier 'Login' has already been declared

Comment: Have you tried `export { Login }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are importing `Login` at the top of `login/index.js` as `import Login from './Login';` it's already declared. The value of `Login` will be the default export that is in your `Login.jsx` file (eg: `export default Login`).

Since it's already declared, you can't redeclare it with `const`. If you want it to be a named export (so you can use it as `import { Login } from './login';`) then you likely want `export { Login }` in your `login/index.js` file:

```
import Login from './Login';

export { Login };
```